# LUN's are not getting mounted

Tags: linux

```
mount -t gfs /dev/vgglobal/lvol1 /packages
mount: permission denied
```

I am running as a root user and I am still getting this error.

Any idea what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have GFS available to test, but here are a few things to try:

- Does anything useful show up in syslog?  Possibly `/var/log/messages`, or just look at `dmesg | tail`.
- Is the device file actually accessible?  Try to read some data from it:

  ```
  xxd -l 100 /dev/vgglobal/lvol1
  ```
- Can you successfully mount non-gfs filesystems on the /packages mount point?

  ```
  mount -t tmpfs none /packages
  umount /packages
  ```

If all of these work successfully, then I guess the problem is GFS specific and someone more familiar with GFS will need to help out.

Answer (score 0):

http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-4262

but it is good to have cluster node and have gfs partitions.